# How to prove the integral by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha\in R.$  Prove that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\int_{(0,n)}(1-\frac{x}{n})^nx^{\alpha-1}dx=\int_{(0,+\infty)}e^{-x}x^{\alpha-1}dx.$$
We know that $(1-\frac{x}{n})^nx^{\alpha-1}$ is increasing and converge to $e^{-x}x^{\alpha-1}.$
The problem is that the domain $(0,n)$is not fixed. Can anyone help me? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need $\alpha >0$ for the integrals to exist. In that case $1-x \leq e^{-x}$ can be used to see that $I_{(0,n)}(x)(1-\frac x n)^{n} x^{\alpha -1}$ is dominated by the  integrable function $e^{-x}x^{\alpha -1}$.

For $\alpha \leq 0$ both sides are $\infty$.

Comment: Many thanks@Kabo Murphy